# How can I have a div element anywhere over other elements on a page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I position a div anywhere on a page? I'm trying to treat it as a popup box. Below is what happens when I use the following code:

```
<div style="width: 100px;padding: 5px; background-color: #CCCCCC;top: 73px; left: 0px">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use absolute positioning:

```
style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px"
```

the `top` and `left` are the x,y coordinates of the top left edge of your div.

Comment: please select it as an answer for future users.

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me, it says I have to wait for some reason I believe it is used to prevent spam.

Comment: @Pete Allport just FYI, it's used to allow for other and possibly better answers before you accept it.

Comment: Please help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258306/how-to-set-a-second-table-inside-a-div-to-a-fixed-position-after-scrolling-down (my absolute position doesn't display the content)

Answer (score 0):

giv the body an `position: relative` and the div a `position: absolute`

This way the div will can be positioned anywhere relative to the body, using top and left properties.

In cases like these it makes more sense to use the css in the head or external file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `position: absolute` to your `div` element's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know more about [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

In your case you can use either `position:absolute;` or `position:fixed;` based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

position: absolute; will not work as you expect when the user has scrolled down on the page.  You'll want to also look at position:fixed, which will position an element relative to the "viewport" (the browser window, no matter where the user has scrolled).

Comment: I used fixed but it displays on top of the page itself rather than the DIV it is within: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258306/how-to-set-a-second-table-inside-a-div-to-a-fixed-position-after-scrolling-down. Please help.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge That is what fixed positioning does. it fixes an element to a specific spot on the page, not relative to the div, no matter where the user scrolls